# How do I add an onchange attribute to a JavaScript generated checkbox that fires when checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dynamic, attributes

I have a large json list of people, they just have an id and a name.
Below I'm looping through it and it's working fine adding a list of checkboxes.

I have another one similar but with a shorter json list and the code's the same so it's not an issue with the json but the way I'm writing my js code.

I'm doing the below.

Creating checkboxes & labels, for each person in obj.people...

```
var peopleLen = obj.People.length;
for (var i = 0; i < peopleLen; i++) {
    if (i < obj.People.length) {
        checkbox = null;
        label = null;
        linebreak = null;

        linebreak = document.createElement('br');
        checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.name = "target";
        checkbox.value = obj.People[i].ID;
        checkbox.id = "cbTarget" + i.toString();
        label = document.createElement('label');
        label.id = "lbTarget" + i.toString();
        label.htmlFor = "cbTarget" + i.toString();
        //This is where I believe it's wrong:
        checkbox.onclick = function () {
            toggleTargetList(obj.People[i].ID);
        };
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0' + obj.People[i].Name));

        document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(checkbox);
        document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(label);
        //Add a line break:
        document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(linebreak);
    }
}
```

The function I'm assigning to it is:

```
function toggleTargetList(t) {
    alert(t);
}
```

A simple alert.

When I change:

```
toggleTargetList(obj.People[i].ID);
```

To:

```
toggleTargetList(obj.People[0].ID);
```

It alerts correctly displaying the first person's id, however when it's `[i]` it alerts the same value (the first value of the json object's people's id property).

I don't see why this is acting up.

It's alerting on assigning the checkbox attribute and not when the actual checkbox is clicked which is another issue.

Comment: Please provide obj.

Comment: JSON is valid. This issue is with constructive logic not with parsing JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkbox.onclick = function () {
            toggleTargetList(obj.People[i].ID);
        };
```

The variable **i** is outside of the scope of the callback function.
Conveniently though you are already assigning the value of `obj.People[i].ID` to the checkboxes **.value** property.

```
checkbox.value = obj.People[i].ID;
```

So simply use this like:

```
checkbox.onclick = function(event) {
  toggleTargetList(event.target.value);
};
```

Comment: Ugh so when I assign `i` it it's assigning `i` explicitly as a reference not a value? It works now though so thanks.

Comment: Yes it will be a reference and hold the last value of i - the length of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as

```js
var obj = {
  People: [{
    ID: 1,
    name: 'Manish'
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    name: 'Manish'
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    name: 'Manish'
  }, {
    ID: 4,
    name: 'Manish'
  }, {
    ID: 5,
    name: 'Manish'
  }]
};

var peopleLen = obj.People.length;

for (var i = 0; i < peopleLen; i++) {
  if (i < obj.People.length) {
    checkbox = null;
    label = null;
    linebreak = null;

    linebreak = document.createElement('br');

    checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.name = "target";
    checkbox.id = "cbTarget" + i.toString();

    // I have added this code
    checkbox.ID = obj.People[i].ID;
    checkbox.onclick = function() {
      toggleTargetList(this.ID);
    };

    label = document.createElement('label');
    label.id = "lbTarget" + i.toString();
    label.innerText = "cbTarget" + i.toString();
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0' + obj.People[i].name));

    document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(checkbox);
    document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(label);
    document.getElementById("divcbTargets").appendChild(linebreak);
  }
}

// I have added this code
function toggleTargetList(index) {
  alert(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="divcbTargets"></div>
```

Also you can have similar onchange event for that.